# get NSRunLoop instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, nsrunloop

I have a class which inherits NSThread:

```
@interface MyService : NSThread {
...
}
```

In another class, I get a instance of `MySerivce`:

```
MyService *service = [self getServiceInstance];

// here, how can I get the NSRunLoop instance out from service ?
```

I want to get the `NSRunLoop` instance of `service` , how to get it?

Comment: How do you start the thread and is it already started, when you want to get the RL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runloop isn't a property of the thread class and you can use [+[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunLoop/currentRunLoop) to get the runloop for the *current* thread.

Note that non-main threads may not have a runloop associated with them, unless you create it yourself.

Comment: But `+[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` returns the run loop of calling thread, I want the NSRunLoop of MyService thread. Could you please use my code snippet to show how to get NSRunLoop of MyService thread. Thanks.

Comment: @Leem.fin You could, of course, store the thread's runloop as an instance variable of the thread class when it starts.  As noted in my answer, you might need to create it first though...

Comment: 'RunLoop.current' for swift 5.2